# Oracle Date TO_CHAR('Month DD, YYYY') has extra spaces in it

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

When I do...

```
Select TO_CHAR (date_field, 'Month DD, YYYY')
from...
```

I get the following:

```
July      01, 2011
April     01, 2011
January   01, 2011
```

**Why are there extra spaces between my month and day?  Why doesn't it just put them next to each other?**

Comment: I got around this issue by doing --- TRIM(TO_CHAR (date_field, 'Month')) || TO_CHAR (date_field, ' DD, YYYY') || ' through ' || TRIM(TO_CHAR(date_field, 'Month')) || TO_CHAR(date_field, ' DD, YYYY').  But I'm curious as to why Oracle does this.

Comment: They do it so your output will be aligned for all months. This is, of course, documented behavior. You just have to tell the DB not to pad it (ie: see my answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you use 'Month' in to_char it right pads to 9 characters; you have to use the abbreviated 'MON', or to_char then trim and concatenate it to avoid this. See, http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

```
select trim(to_char(date_field, 'month')) || ' ' || to_char(date_field,'dd, yyyy')
  from ...
```

or

```
select to_char(date_field,'mon dd, yyyy')
  from ...
```

Comment: I guess I see why Oracle does this, however it is not ideal for all scenarios :|

Comment: @contactmatt, I *think* it's solely because September is 9 characters, that doesn't stop it being ridiculous.

Comment: @Ben - It's not ridiculous, it just dates from a time when it made perfect sense for the default to be to ensure that columnar data came out in fixed width because it was being written to reports that relied on that behavior.  NullUserException's suggestion to use the 'fm' modifier is the proper way to indicate to Oracle that you don't want the default blank-padding behavior.

Comment: NullUserException's answer (below) is a more elegant way to go.

Comment: I think that's widely acknowledged @fasttrainofthoughts... Have you seen the vote totals? This was written by me a very long time ago when I didn't know much. Unfortunately I can't delete it because the OP accepted it. It's obvious that you should use Nulls, so I don't think it matters...

Answer (score 84):

> Why are there extra spaces between my month and day? Why does't it just put them next to each other?

So your output will be aligned.

If you don't want padding use the format modifier `FM`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (date_field, 'fmMonth DD, YYYY') 
  FROM ...;
```

Reference: [Format Model Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216)

Comment: Note that `to_char(date_field, 'fmMonth') || to_char(date_field, ' DD, YYYY')` may be necessary if the `fm` modifier should have an effet only on the month, not the leading zeroes of the day.

Comment: "so your output will be aligned"  Hmmm.... Only if your font is a monospace font.  And it seldom is monospace if you're using "month" formatter, because chances are you'll be showing this output to end-users who never work in monospace.

Comment: Thanks! `fmMonth` as date format trim automatically full month name. Works also with `fmDay` for day name. This should be accepted answer...

Answer (score 6):

You should use fm element to delete blank spaces.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'fmDAY DD "de" MONTH "de" YYYY') CURRENT_DATE
FROM   dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> -- original . . .
SQL> select
  2  to_char( sysdate, 'Day "the" Ddth "of" Month, yyyy' ) dt
  3  from dual;

DT
----------------------------------------
Friday    the 13th of May      , 2016

SQL>
SQL> -- collapse repeated spaces . . .
SQL> select
  2  regexp_replace(
  3      to_char( sysdate, 'Day "the" Ddth "of" Month, yyyy' ),
  4      '  * *', ' ') datesp
  5  from dual;

DATESP
----------------------------------------
Friday the 13th of May , 2016

SQL>
SQL> -- and space before commma . . .
SQL> select
  2  regexp_replace(
  3      to_char( sysdate, 'Day "the" Ddth "of" Month, yyyy' ),
  4      '  *(,*) *', '\1 ') datesp
  5  from dual;

DATESP
----------------------------------------
Friday the 13th of May, 2016

SQL>
SQL> -- space before punctuation . . .
SQL> select
  2  regexp_replace(
  3      to_char( sysdate, 'Day "the" Ddth "of" Month, yyyy' ),
  4      '  *([.,/:;]*) *', '\1 ') datesp
  5  from dual;

DATESP
----------------------------------------
Friday the 13th of May, 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
select to_char(to_date('01/10/2017','dd/mm/yyyy'),'fmMonth fmDD,YYYY') from dual;

select to_char(sysdate,'fmMonth fmDD,YYYY') from dual;
```

Comment: if you use: SELECT TO_CHAR (date_field, 'fmMonth DD, YYYY') 
  FROM ...; then query will return for DD 1 for 01,same as 2 to 9 
But if you use SELECT TO_CHAR (date_field, 'fmMonth fmDD, YYYY') 
  FROM ... then it will return for DD as 01

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain also the information from the comment for better readability, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-fmMONTH-YYYY') "Date" from Dual;

The above query result will be as given below.

### Date

01-APRIL-2019

Comment: In the above query, the date result will retain the leading 0 to represent the day as 01 and there is no whitespace after the month APRIL. If you want the month to be spelled in propercase use the below format. select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-fmMonth-YYYY') "Date" from Dual; Then the result will display as '01-April-2019'