# Oracle adding trailing whitespace to my to_char(date)

Tags: oracle

This is my statement:

```
select distinct FIELD1||';'||to_char(FIELD_DATE, 'yyyymmdd') BDATE 
 from MYTABLE;
```

Result has several whitespaces after the date...why?How to solve this?
I tried both

```
to_char(FIELD_DATE, 'fmyyyymmdd')
```

and

```
trim(to_char(FIELD_DATE, 'yyyymmdd'))
```

but nothing..

edit:
This question is similar [Oracle Date TO_CHAR('Month DD, YYYY') has extra spaces in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166446/), nevetheless the answer works because "Month" is responsible for this Oracle behaviour. In my case I am just using "mm" so there should not be any problem...

Comment: The `fmyyyymmdd` format mask will remove the trailing whitespace.  What leads you to believe that it is not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Date TO\_CHAR('Month DD, YYYY') has extra spaces in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166446/oracle-date-to-charmonth-dd-yyyy-has-extra-spaces-in-it)

Comment: The fact it is not happening...

Comment: @Phate - When I run with a format mask of `fmyyyymmdd` on my system, there is no trailing whitespace.  If you are seeing different behavior, you'll need to post a test case that shows exactly what you are seeing that we can reproduce.

Comment: What tool are you using to run your query?  Show us the output of: select to_char(FIELD_DATE, 'yyyymmdd'), length(to_char(FIELD_DATE, 'yyyymmdd')) from MYTABLE;

Comment: Since Trim() definitely removes trailing spaces, you're impression that it does not mist be wrong, which calls into question your impression that the format mask fmyyyymmdd also has trailing spaces. Use Length() to measure the string.