# Removing whitespace between comma seperated values

Tags: sql, oracle, date, whitespace

I have a column of date that is initially in a numeric stance i.e. `20200422` (2020 being the year,04 being the month and so on).

I have written a query that is concatenating a particular value with the above date.

The above date is then converted using TO_CHAR to get only the month and year for example (from 20200422, i've extracted only `2020` and `04` in the format of = `April,2020`).

The issue that I am facing that i have retrieved the desired result but there is a huge amount of whitespace between the year and month.

The format is shown below as an example.

A field called as name and date are concatenated.

`TOM (April _____, 2020)`

What can i do to remove the whitespace that is appearing right after the month i.e. April.

I'm leaving behind the query in a dummy format. Please help. Thank you so much in advance

P.S. whitespace weren't displayed so i used the symbole '_' to represent them. Thank you

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    select CONCAT((replace(abc.NAME, SUBSTR(abc.NAME, 0, 6), '******')),' ('|| TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(abc.DATE,'YYYYMMDD'),'Month, yyyy')||')')
    from TABLECUSTOMER abc 
    where CUSTOMER_NAME = 'TOMMY SHELBY'  
    order by abc.CUSTOMERID DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle Date TO\_CHAR('Month DD, YYYY') has extra spaces in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166446/oracle-date-to-charmonth-dd-yyyy-has-extra-spaces-in-it)

Comment: Thank you so so much Bro. Yes it does.